# How to enable ipv6 on the loopback device?

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I'm trying to enable inet6 on my loopback device. I added the following in the /etc/network/interfaces file and restated networking. But `ifconfig lo` still only shows `inet addr` and not `inet6 addr`.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
```

I use a Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS machine.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you paste the output of `ifconfig lo` or `ip addr show dev lo` (add to the question please)?

Comment: What shows `cat /proc/cmdline` Ipv6 is normaly on under xenial.  `cat  /etc/sysctl.d/10-ipv6-privacy.conf `

Answer (score 5):

The issue was that ipv6 was disabled in sysctl. Once I enabled, both eth0 and lo had ipv6 addresses.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.eth0.disable_ipv6=0
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6=0
```